# Apply transformation matrix to point cloud

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

this seems to be a particularly stupid question but I didn't manage to find an answer in the docs:

How can I apply a transformation matrix (Translation and Rotation) to a point cloud, i.e., to every point in the cloud.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: Probably using just matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix multiplication. If your transformation matrix is a 4x4 matrix, you wil have to pad your points with a 1.

```
T  = [1, 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1];
P1 = [1; 2; 3];
P2 = T * [P1; 1];
```

If you would like to apply the transformation to the whole cloud you will have to use cells. If you want to make it fast, try [this](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37515-mmx-multithreaded-matrix-operations-on-n-d-matrices) library

Comment: MATLAB (at least for `affine3d`) uses the convention of multiplying the points by the transformation matrix: `p * T`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine3d-class.html#properties. Why would you need to use a cell array to transform multiple points? Multiplying an `n x 4` array of points by the transformation matrix should be sufficient, correct?